# Can I share class instances between two processes on the same machine without having to serialize/deserialize?

Tags: c#, windows-7, named-pipes, memory-mapped-files

I have fairly large collections of object instances (>100mb) that I need to share between two processes on the same machine. Is there a way to share such collections without having to serialize/deserialize?

I considered a message bus but then I would need to serialize/deserialize the object instances and that is a no-go because the overhead is too time consuming. Also memory mapped files seem to involve the serialization of the object instances to files.

I target C#/.Net 4.5 on a Windows 7 OS.

Thanks

Comment: Have you ever considered to use database?

Comment: @VladimirMezentsev, a DB would be way too slow and the data will not be re-used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't share a live object between processes.

You can't force the .NET to keep an object in a memory mapped are of memory and/or to attach an object to the "data" present in a memory mapped area of memory.

Once upon a time there was .NET Remoting to communicate between processes... It was very very low level... it is still present, but is obsolete. Through the use of internal black magic, sometimes (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/7553467/613130) instead of serializing/deserializing objects it is able to create a "proxy" on one side to access the data on the other side. Note that clearly this is slow. Ah... and proxied objects aren't really "local"... I think the non-owner has to make a call to the owner of the objects (the "server") to make any operation on the proxied objects. So they are "shared" like you would share a file on your HD: "client" computers can read it, but to read it, the "server" has to read it and send the read data to the "client".

Comment: what do you mean with "live object"?

Comment: @MattWolf A "real" .net object, not a "serialized object"... You can easily share a serialized object: you put it (the serialized data I mean) in a memory mapped file and multiple processes can read it.

Comment: I am aware of that but I wonder whether Pipes or any other technology can share the unserialized objects

Comment: @MattWolf As I've written: no. You can't with memory maps, and you surely can't with other technologies. In the end, somewhere the object will be serialized/deserialized/directly copied without serialization (probably .NET remoting does the last when necessary). If it was possible to tell the .NET "attach an object at this address of memory" (so transform a native pointer to a managed pointer) then many things would be possible... But it isn't possible.

Comment: ...hence my asking the question. Thanks for your help and information.

Comment: @MattWolf What are the objects you want to share? Big `string`s? Big `float[]` arrays? Big `byte[]` arrays? Because you could try to reimplement the part of your objects that use much memory to use unmanaged memory... in that way you could share it through a memory map.

Comment: large collections of custom class object instances. Sometimes up to 1mln objects. Serializing those would take around 30 seconds even on a pretty higher performant machine.

Comment: @MattWolf Then there is nothing that can be done... You could try to use a faster serializer... or perhaps even .NET Remoting... but I don't see a magic bullet that can solve all your problems, especially if the object graph is complex.

Comment: thanks a lot, I gotta overthink how to work around this: Essentially I have a backend that generates data points that will be visualized in the front-end application. I tried Protocol Buffers and fast JSON serializers and it just takes too long to serialize.